# Rails production render JS partial from app/views/model

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, partial, assets, production

Hello everyone!

I have a partial file called `_more_contacts.js.coffee` in `app/views/contacts/`

This partial is rendered via an Ajax call to the `ContactsController`, and update another partial (`_more_contacts.html.erb`) in a view:

Ajax call:

```
<%= link_to "blah", more_contacts_path(@smthg) , method: :post, remote: true, id: "more_contacts", data: {last: raw(@id)} %>
```

Controller code:

```
def more_contacts  
  @contacts = Contact.search(params)
  respond_to do |format|  
    format.js { render partial: "more_contacts" }  
  end  
end
```

JS Partial code:

```
$('#more_contacts_table').append('<%=j render partial: "more_contacts", formats: [:html] %>')
```

HTML Partial:

```
<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to contact.company, contact_path(contact.id) %></td>
    <td><%= contact.email %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Note that I struggled a couple of hours to find out that it shouldn't have the `.erb` extension, even though it contains some ruby code...

Anyway, everything works great in development, but I can't make it works in production :(
I have tried the following in my `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.serve_static_assets = false  
config.assets.compress = true  
config.assets.compile = true  
config.assets.digest = true  

config.assets.precompile += %w( contacts/more_contacts.js app/views/contacts/more_contacts.js )  
config.assets.precompile << "contacts/_more_contacts.js"  
config.assets.precompile << "#{Rails.root}/app/views/contacts/_more_contacts.js"  
config.assets.precompile << "#{Rails.root}/app/views/contacts/_more_contacts.js.coffee"  
config.assets.precompile << "#{Rails.root}/app/views/contacts/more_contacts.js"  
config.assets.precompile << "#{Rails.root}/app/views/contacts/more_contacts.js.coffee"
```

But when I run my rake task to compile the assets, more_contacts.js is nowhere to be found (`public/assets/manifest.yml` or `public/assets/`) and the Ajax call fails...

I'm stuck here :( Any idea, anyone?

Comment: Fixed it by moving coffee-rails out of the assets group in my Gemfile...  
  
Thanks to : `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926034/rails-javascript-views-not-working-in-production?rq=1` for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by moving coffee-rails out of the assets group in my Gemfile, thanks to [Rails JavaScript views not working in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926034/).